# Sum of n terms of series

Tags: summation

Find the sum of the $n$ terms of the following series:
$$\frac{1}{1+1^2+1^4}+\frac{2}{1+2^2+2^4}+\frac{3}{1+3^2+3^4}+\dots$$
[[Original Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGshB.jpg)

I tried it a lot .

But don't get a proper start .

Comment: First,  derive this relation: $\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{n}{1+n^2+n^4} = \frac{m^2+m}{2(m^2+m+1)}$. You can try this by induction, but look for a neat method if possible.Take $m \to \infty$ to see what happens,

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг It's easy to prove that relation using induction but how did you find it in the first place?

Comment: @Hugh do PFD and telescoping.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Simply Beautifully said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $k$th term of the series is $$\frac {k}{1+k^2+k^4} = \frac {k}{(1+k^2)^2-k^2} = \frac {k}{(1+k^2+k)(1+k^2-k)} = \frac {1}{2 (1+k^2-k)} - \frac {1}{2 (1+k^2+k)} $$ Thus, we have a telescoping series. Thus, the sum of the first $n $ terms is: $$\frac {1}{2 (1+1^2-1)} - \frac {1}{2(1+n^2+n)} =\frac {n^2+n}{2 (1+n+n^2)} $$ Hope it helps.

Comment: :There is a typo in 2nd line 2nd term.

Comment: @MatheMagic Thank you. I was on my phone. Thank you again.